# Rmarkdown is not generating bookmarks's list in PDF side panel

Tags: r-markdown, rstudio, pdf-generation, knitr, tableofcontents

I'm using RStudio in Ubuntu with Rmarkdown and Knitr to generated a PDF file output.

Until an hour ago my pdf files where being generated with the bookmarks list in the pdf side panel. Now this stopped being done and only the TOC in the first page is being generated.

Any hints on what may be happening here? Is there any config or tweak that I should do?

My YAML header is as follows:

```
---
title: "Cálculo"
author: "Gustavo Mirapalheta"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output:
  pdf_document:
    number_sections: true
    toc: true
    toc_depth: 4
subtitle: Uma Abordagem Computacional
documentclass: report
header-includes: \usepackage{float} \graphicspath{{./imagens/}} \usepackage[brazil]{babel} \usepackage{enumitem} \usepackage{alphalph} \usepackage{makeidx} \usepackage{amssymb} \usepackage{supertabular} \usepackage{array} \usepackage{hhline} \usepackage{soul, color}  \definecolor{codegray}{rgb}{0.93,0.93,0.93} \sethlcolor{codegray} \usepackage{Sweavel}
link-citations: yes
nocite: |
  @canale, @demidovitch, @dirac, @nielsen, @mcmahon, @strang1
bibliography:
- books.bib
- packages.bib
biblio-style: apalike
---
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys, I was not looking at the right place in the pdf viewer. Must be getting old... I didn't find in the stackoverflow interface the option to just delete my question, this is why it remains (so far...) here.